# faithful modules that aren't free

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, free-modules

What are some examples of faithful modules that are not free?
It is clear that free modules are faithful but would the converse be true also?

Comment: For Commutative rings

Comment: There are certainly faithful modules that aren't free.  To find a simple example, think about $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well-known that if an ideal of a ring is free, then it is principal. Hence, every non-principal ideal of a domain is a faithful non-free module. For example, in the ring $R:=\mathbb{Z}[x, y]$, the ideals $\langle x+n, y+m\rangle$ for all $m, n\in\mathbb{Z}$ are faithful non-free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. By this method we can construct many examples!!!

Answer (score 2):

*Counterexample*:

$\mathbf{Q/Z}$ is a faithful *torsion* module.

Answer (score 2):

$\prod_{n=2}^\infty \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is another faithful torsion $\mathbb Z$-module (hence certainly not free), apparently distinct from Bernard's since this one is uncountable.

For another one, try a nontrivial right ideal $T$ of $R=M_2(F_2)$ where $F_2$ is the field of two elements.  $T$ is faithful since all nonzero unital modules of $R$ are faithful, and it can't be free purely because of cardinality. It also happens to be "torsion" in the sense that its elements all have nonzero annihilators.